# Running shell script with more information

Tags: bash, shell

My script get stuck in some point and it doesn't show any error. I would like to know why and where it gets stuck. Is there a possibility to run a script and show me more information what is it running?
I have found `-x` command to run it in debug mode but I have a lot of scripts which are connected and it doesn't work for me. 
With `-vvv` I have also tried, but somehow it doesn't show more than without it.

Does anyone know another command for that?

Comment: "My script get stuck" What script? There isn't a default `-v` option for each bash utility, please share the script thats failing!

Comment: @Carina : You could as a habit put in all your scripts as the first statement a `[ ${XTRACE:-no} = yes ] && set -x`. Once this is done, you just have to run your script with `XTRACE=yes yourscript.sh` and get a full trace.

Answer (score 0):

Read:
https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html

... and this:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script

... and if that's not enough, look at the gdb-like bash debugger:
http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/

and many moore...